# Complex Netsuite Nest Case WHEN Query

Tags: case, netsuite

I am trying to build a complex CASE WHEN statement for a Saved Search in NetSuite.

This is the "LONG" version, but obviously it has too many characters and I know it can be simplified, but I'm not sure how.

```
CASE WHEN {status} = 'Cancelled' THEN 0

WHEN {subsidiary} = 'Ciatti Australia' 
  AND {status} = 'Billed' 
  AND {applyingtransaction.custbody_shared_comm_type} = 'Ciatti Internal - 50/50 share between Selling/Buying office' 
  THEN {applyingtransaction.fxamount}/2

WHEN {subsidiary} = 'Ciatti Australia' 
  AND {status} = 'Billed' 
  AND {applyingtransaction.custbody_shared_comm_type} = 'Ciatti/iDeal - 1/3 share between Selling office, iDeal & Mr Li etc. (2/3 to iDeal)' 
  THEN {applyingtransaction.fxamount}/3 

WHEN {subsidiary} = 'Ciatti Australia' 
  AND {status} = 'Billed' 
  AND {applyingtransaction.custbody_shared_comm_type} = 'Ciatti/iDeal - Existing Supplier/Existing Buyer - 1/3 to iDeal' 
  THEN {applyingtransaction.fxamount}/3*2 

WHEN {subsidiary} = 'Ciatti Australia' 
  AND {status} = 'Billed' 
  AND {applyingtransaction.custbody_shared_comm_type} = 'Ciatti/iDeal - Existing Supplier/New Buyer - 50/50 share between Selling office and iDeal' 
  THEN {applyingtransaction.fxamount}/2 

WHEN {subsidiary} = 'Ciatti Australia' 
  AND {status} = 'Billed' 
  AND {applyingtransaction.custbody_shared_comm_type} = 'Ciatti/iDeal - New Suppler/Existing Buyer - 1/3 share between Selling office, AU office and iDeal' 
  THEN {applyingtransaction.fxamount}/3*2 

WHEN {subsidiary} = 'Ciatti Australia' 
  AND {status} = 'Billed' 
  AND {applyingtransaction.custbody_shared_comm_type} = 'Ciatti/iDeal - New Supplier/New Buyer - 50/50 share between Selling office and iDeal' 
  THEN {applyingtransaction.fxamount}/2 

WHEN {subsidiary} = 'Ciatti Australia' 
  AND {status} = 'Billed' 
  AND {applyingtransaction.custbody_shared_comm_type} = 'Not to be shared' 
  THEN {applyingtransaction.fxamount} 

WHEN {subsidiary} = 'Ciatti Australia' 
  AND {custbody_shared_comm_type} = 'Ciatti Internal - 50/50 share between Selling/Buying office' 
  THEN {fxamount}/2 

WHEN {subsidiary} = 'Ciatti Australia' 
  AND {custbody_shared_comm_type} = 'Ciatti/iDeal - 1/3 share between Selling office, iDeal & Mr Li etc. (2/3 to iDeal)' 
  THEN {fxamount}/3 

WHEN {subsidiary} = 'Ciatti Australia' 
  AND {custbody_shared_comm_type} = 'Ciatti/iDeal - Existing Supplier/Existing Buyer - 1/3 to iDeal' 
  THEN {fxamount}/3 

WHEN {subsidiary} = 'Ciatti Australia' 
  AND {custbody_shared_comm_type} = 'Ciatti/iDeal - Existing Supplier/New Buyer - 50/50 share between Selling office and iDeal' 
  THEN {fxamount}/2 

WHEN {subsidiary} = 'Ciatti Australia' 
  AND {custbody_shared_comm_type} = 'Ciatti/iDeal - New Suppler/Existing Buyer - 1/3 share between Selling office, AU office and iDeal' 
  THEN {fxamount}/3 

WHEN {subsidiary} = 'Ciatti Australia' 
  AND {custbody_shared_comm_type} = 'Ciatti/iDeal - New Supplier/New Buyer - 50/50 share between Selling office and iDeal' 
  THEN {fxamount}/2 

WHEN {subsidiary} = 'Ciatti Australia' 
  AND {custbody_shared_comm_type} = 'Not to be shared' 
  THEN {fxamount}/2
```

__

Then the same as above when the Subsidiary is NOT 'Ciatti Australia'.

Answer (score 0):

One way to reduce the formula is to use the internal id of the field instead of the text value. This can be done by adding ".id" to the field, i.e.

```
{custbody_shared_comm_type}
```

to

```
{custbody_shared_comm_type.id}
```

and the case will change from

```
WHEN {subsidiary.id} = 1
  AND {custbody_shared_comm_type} = 'Ciatti/iDeal - 1/3 share between Selling office, iDeal & Mr Li etc. (2/3 to iDeal)' 
  THEN {fxamount}/3
```

to

```
WHEN {subsidiary.id} = 1 
  AND {custbody_shared_comm_type.id} = 4 
  THEN {fxamount}/3
```

Another is to create embedded case clauses to remove the repetition of lines like

WHEN {subsidiary} = 'Ciatti Australia'
AND {status} = 'Billed'

i.e.

```
CASE WHEN {status} = 'Cancelled' THEN 0

WHEN {subsidiary} = 'Ciatti Australia' 
  AND {status} = 'Billed' 
  THEN
    CASE WHEN
    {applyingtransaction.custbody_shared_comm_type} = 'Ciatti Internal - 50/50 share between Selling/Buying office' THEN {applyingtransaction.fxamount}/2

    CASE WHEN {applyingtransaction.custbody_shared_comm_type} = 'Ciatti/iDeal - 1/3 share between Selling office, iDeal & Mr Li etc. (2/3 to iDeal)' THEN {applyingtransaction.fxamount}/3 

    CASE WHEN {applyingtransaction.custbody_shared_comm_type} = 'Ciatti/iDeal - Existing Supplier/Existing Buyer - 1/3 to iDeal' THEN {applyingtransaction.fxamount}/3*2 
    .
    .
    .
    ELSE 0
  END
WHEN {subsidiary} = 'Ciatti Australia' 
  AND NOT {status} = 'Billed' THEN
  .
  .
  .

WHEN NOT {subsidiary} = 'Ciatti Australia' 
  AND {status} = 'Billed' 
  THEN
    CASE WHEN ...

    CASE WHEN ...

    CASE WHEN ...
    .
    .
    .
    ELSE 0
  END

WHEN NOT {subsidiary} = 'Ciatti Australia' 
  AND NOT {status} = 'Billed' 
  THEN
    CASE WHEN ...

    CASE WHEN ...

    CASE WHEN ...
    .
    .
    .
    ELSE 0
  END
```

When the two are combined, the result would be something like :

```
CASE WHEN {status} = 'Cancelled' THEN 0

WHEN {subsidiary.id} = 1
  AND {status} = 'Billed' 
  THEN
    CASE WHEN {applyingtransaction.custbody_shared_comm_type.id} = 1 THEN {applyingtransaction.fxamount}/2

    CASE WHEN {applyingtransaction.custbody_shared_comm_type.id} = 2 THEN {applyingtransaction.fxamount}/3 

    CASE WHEN {applyingtransaction.custbody_shared_comm_type.id} = 3 THEN {applyingtransaction.fxamount}/3*2 
    .
    .
    .
    ELSE 0
  END
WHEN {subsidiary.id} = 1
  AND NOT {status} = 'Billed' THEN
  .
  .
  .

WHEN NOT {subsidiary.id} = 1
  AND {status} = 'Billed' 
  THEN
    CASE WHEN ...

    CASE WHEN ...

    CASE WHEN ...
    .
    .
    .
    ELSE 0
  END

WHEN NOT {subsidiary.id} = 1
  AND NOT {status} = 'Billed' 
  THEN
    CASE WHEN ...

    CASE WHEN ...

    CASE WHEN ...
    .
    .
    .
    ELSE 0
  END
```

Obviously replacing the actual subsidiary ids and correct ids for string representations in your examples.